# The color gets changed via script but doesn't get updated in game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a simple line that basically makes the light color switch according to 3 color values.

`GameObject.Find("Directional Light").GetComponent<Light>().color = new Color(color.R, color.G, color.B, 255);`

But when I actually use it (I made it so it gets triggered when I press C), the color value itself gets changed, but it's not updated until I change it manualy through inspector.

[image]

If anyone knows how I can fix it, I would be very grateful.

It's the same thing with Camera background color, and I am really unsure if it's me doing something wrong about changing the color, me not doing something that has to be done for it to update, or it just not working like that.

I tried changing the color property with a matching color value. It should have changed AND updated so the change can be observed in game, but instead the new color value is stored in the inspector's color menu, and won't change until I actually change it manually. There are no errors, and the color DOES appear in the inspector, it's just not changed to.

Comment: The value of `color.R, color.G, color.B` should set between 0f-1f.

Comment: @WillardPeng thanks, I had to divide all color values by 255 and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Color values had to be divided by 255 due to `Color` only accepting values from 0 to 1

So, it will be
`color.R/255, color.G/255, color.B/255`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
GameObject.Find("Directional Light").GetComponent<Light>().color = new Color(4, 191, 4, 255);
```